# Programmatically accessing power Button android?

Tags: android, ios, power-off

Is there any way to programmatically access power button in android and even on IOS.

Comment: What do you mean, exactly, Gopi? Do you want to programmatically trigger a shutdown?

Comment: i am developing an anti theft app, in that i am building siren option, (i.e when u send siren command to an android device it starts sirening for 1 min) but if i press power button siren stops thats the reason is there any way to stop the power button for 1 min

Comment: That makes no sense, Gopi. You can't "stop" a physical button. You want to block whatever is silencing the alarm, I'm guessing.

Comment: even if the theif press the power button the device should not respond until the siren stop's. i know that long press of power button will shut down the device and no problem with that.

Comment: Thanks you Michael, but its most important that i have to complete the task within today i just need whether it can be done or not.

Comment: i have a question, 1.i can access vol down and vol up button programmatically even lock and back button which is physical buttons and y cant with power button.

Comment: There are some system/admin restriction, which are not allowed to access anyway :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apple is not allowing you to use hardware components completely. They have added some restrictions.  They provided the method in the app delegate i.e. `applicationDidEnterBackground` can catch the home button press .Also they has provided the the API's to access the camera,bluetooth etc .At least this much of API's I know which provided by apple publicly to access the hardware. You cannot access the other hardware elements in your application which not provided publicly by apple .If you are able to do this by any way then also your application will not approved by apple .

Answer (score 3):

Yes there is a way you can detect the press of power Button in android.
Use this code

```
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
      if (event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_POWER) //KEYCODE.POWER determines the press of power Button
 {
    // do what you want with the power button
     return true;
 }
  return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
 }
```

Comment: hi raw, my problem is i have to stop response of power button until my siren stops (when i send anti theft command to android device and device starts siren for 1 mins and until that there should be no response for device by user)

Comment: please elaborate more, I am not properly getting you?

Comment: you can do one thing . Just do your coding and return it as false if siren is running, if siren stops return True from that button :)
make your key code == 0 ; it will do noting then 1;

Comment: yes is it possible . i will find some code for you paste your email id here